# How to render a Jinja2 macro from a view callable?

Tags: python, templates, macros, pyramid, jinja2

I have some macros defined that are called from several templates.

For example, the Product page has a Review section that uses the macros defined in `'helpers/review.jinja2'` to print each review. The `'helpers/review.jinja2'` file has this two macros:

```
{% macro render_review(request,review) -%}
{% macro render_review_comment(request,comment) -%}
```

When someone submits a new review, via ajax, I want to return the rendered review in order to append the content to the Review section.

Right now, I have an intermediate template `'review/review.jinja2'` that looks like this:

```
{% import 'helpers/review.jinja2' as review_helper %}
{{ review_helper.render_review(request,review) }}
```

This template is rendered from the view:

```
@view_config(route_name='review.add_review', renderer='review/review.jinja2')
def add_review(request):
    return dict(review=my_new_review)
```

But I hope there is a better way to do this. So, is it possible to render a macro defined in a template?

Thanks

Comment: I just did a quick search through Jinja2's docs and it doesn't look like there's any way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

The solution can actually be found in another one of Armin's projects - Flask implements a [`get_template_attribute`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.get_template_attribute) method (see [here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/src/flask/helpers.py#L377) for the source of the method).  This points us at Jinja2's `Template` class, more specifically, the `Template` class' [`module` attribute](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.Template.module).

I don't know if Pyramid's default renderer for Jinja2 exposes that functionality for you, but it should be possible to create and register a custom renderer if the default one does not let you do something like this (entirely theoretical):

```
@view_config(route_name='review.add_review',
                renderer='helpers/review.jinja2:render_review')
def add_review(request):
    return dict(review=my_new_review)
```

Comment: It did not work with plain pyramid. It looks complicated, but I will try it one more time :D

Answer (score 0):

This method was suggested elsewhere, it helped me:

```
@app.route("/test")
def test_view():
    t = app.jinja_env.get_template('macros.html')
    mod = t.make_module({'request': request})
    return mod.my_macro()
```

[Render Jinja2 macro without bothering what's in the rest of the template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21521566/67416)